# create border bottom only programmatically

Tags: swift, uiview

I am trying to create bottom only border. I have been searching for the answer but nothing seem to work and Xcode does not give any error at all.

here is my border code

```
func addborder(let theobject:AnyObject){
    let object = theobject
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: object.frame.size.height - width, width:  object.frame.size.width, height: object.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width
    object.layer.addSublayer(border)
    object.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

here is the code for the UILabel that I create programmatically:

```
let jobtype1title = UILabel()
//jobtype1title.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
jobtype1title.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
jobtype1title.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
jobtype1title.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(scrollView.frame.size.width).active = true
jobtype1title.frame.size.height = 10
jobtype1title.textAlignment = .Center
addborder(jobtype1title)
scrollView.addSubview(jobtype1title)
jobtype1title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
jobtype1title.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.centerXAnchor).active = true
jobtype1title.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20).active = true
```

I am adding the label into the Scrollview and I am trying to create a UIView (that will become the border into the `jobtype1title` label). am I missing something in the label? I try to use add border function to another label that I made with storyboard and it works. but this label that I create programmatically does not. what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

> i try to use add border function to another label that i made with storyboard and it works. but this label that i create programmatically does not. what did i miss?

The problem is that your `addborder` depends for its operation on knowing the `frame` of the `object` to which it is adding a layer:

```
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: object.frame.size.height - width, width:  object.frame.size.width, height: object.frame.size.height)
```

The UILabel that you made in the storyboard has a frame, so that code works.

But your `jobtype1title` label has *no* meaningful frame at the time you call `addborder`; it will get its frame from constraints and autolayout, and that hasn't happened yet at this time. Until layout is actually performed, the label has basically a zero size. Thus, the border is added, but you can't see it because it has zero size too.